# Why Connection refused got when connecting to LocalServerSocket from native program in Android

Tags: android, sockets, unix-socket

There is a java server LocalServerSocket listening on an abstract unix domain socket which named 'myaudsocket', like as:

```java
public void listen() {
    String name = "myaudsocket";
    mSocket = new LocalServerSocket(name);
    LocalSocket client = mSocket.accept();
    ...
}
```

I can connect the server by below Java code:

```
public void connect() {
    String name = "myaudsocket";
    LocalSocket client = new LocalSocket();
    client.connect(new LocalSocketAddress(name));
    Log.d("client", "connected to " + name);
}
```

But if I can not connect to the server by the native code:

```
#define SOKET_NAME "@myaudsocket"
void connect() {
    char* name = SOKET_NAME;
    struct sockaddr_un addr;
    int sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("failed to create socket");
        return -1;
    }

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(addr.sun_path, SOKET_NAME, sizeof(addr.sun_path)-1);
    if (name[0] == '@') 
       addr.sun_path[0] = '\0';
    
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
        perror("failed to connect");
        close(sock);
        return -1;
    }
    ...
}
```

The console always said: "failed to connect: Connection refused". But the above native code can work in general Linux OS (such as Ubuntu).

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Why are you setting the first byte to NUL? It's the *last* byte that needs to be NUL.

Comment: @user207421 refer to https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html, it is said that "abstract: an abstract socket address is distinguished (from a
          pathname socket) by the fact that sun_path[0] is a null byte
          ('\0')."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is about the address length. From the offical reference example https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html, the address length parament of connect() is `sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)`.

It can work in normal Linux system (such as Ubuntu). But it can not work in android. From the source of libcutils:

https://android-opengrok.bangnimang.net/android-9.0.0_r61/xref/system/core/libcutils/socket_local_client_unix.cpp?r=db87e6d1#111

We can see the address length is set at the ending null character, not include the padding zeros.

```cpp
*alen = namelen + offsetof(struct sockaddr_un, sun_path) + 1;
```

After changing the code as:

```cpp
#define SOKET_NAME "@myaudsocket"
void connect() {
    char* name = SOKET_NAME;
    struct sockaddr_un addr;

    // add this variant
    int alen;

    int sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("failed to create socket");
        return -1;
    }

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(addr.sun_path, SOKET_NAME, sizeof(addr.sun_path)-1);
    if (name[0] == '@') 
        addr.sun_path[0] = '\0';

    // Added this line 
    alen = offsetof(struct sockaddr_un, sun_path) + strlen(name);
    
    // change sizeof(addr) to alen
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, alen) < 0) {
        perror("failed to connect");
        close(sock);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

It works.